# How to organize Visual Studio publish folder?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, web, iis

I have a few questions about the publishing process of an ASP NET Core app in Visual Studio:

1. Is it possible to change the name of wwwroot without repercurssions?

   - I mean, in html code for the Razor Page, if have elements that fetch 
     images and fonts from that directory. Some have inline CSS. But
     whenI    change the name of the root folder, it spoils everything.
     Doesn't    keep the fonts or the original style.
2. In the runtimes folder, I have folders for Unix, Win x64, Win x86,
       etc. Can't I specify one of these OS, in the Build Settings, for
       example?
3. Is it possible to keep the all the dependency files, dll files, in a
   specific folder, when I publish?

This is only to have a better organization in the end.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. By default, `WWWRoot` folder in the Asp.Net Core project is treated as a web root folder. Static files can be stored in any folder under the web root and accessed with a relative path to that root.
   We can rename `WWWRoot` folder to any other name as per our choice and set it as a web root by the below method while preparing hosting environment in the Program.cs.

   ```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
       }

       public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
               {
                  //custom the web root foler.
                   webBuilder.UseWebRoot("wwwroot1");
                   webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
               });
   ```

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1
2. In order to build a cross-platform asp.net core application, we could specify the target runtime identity with RuntimeIdentifiers(RID).
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#runtimeidentifiers
   Also, we could opt in to it in the publish Overview.
   [image]
   Check this for more details.
   https://stackify.com/cross-platform-net-core-apps/
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog
3. Whether to package dependency files or not, we usually call this solution deployment mode(self-contained deployment and framework-dependent deployment).
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/